# How to retrieve value from DateTimePicker as epoch in milliseconds & pass this value to Google API Direction request?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, jquery-plugins

[Image of current functionality](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hxmTo.png)

Hi I'm using the **'xdsoft datetimepicker jquery plugin'** (http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/) within my application so the user can select a date/time of arrival to a set destination.

Currently my application is using Google's Javascript API & lets the user toggle between 2 travel modes - either Transit or Driving (As seen in the image I've uploaded above)

**Google Javascript API Request:**

```
 directionsService.route({
  origin: pos,
  destination: {lat: *Value*,lng: *Value*}, 

   travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode[selectedMode],
   transitOptions: {
   modes: ['RAIL'],
   **************
   arrivalTime: new Date(), <<< *** WHERE I NEED TO PASS DATE/TIME PICKER VALUE
   **************
   routingPreference: 'FEWER_TRANSFERS'
},
    unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.IMPERIAL,
     provideRouteAlternatives: true
}, function(response, status) {

  if (status == 'OK') {
    directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
  } else {
    window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
  }
});
 }
```

I'm not sure how to pass the date/time value from the picker into 'arrivalTime: new Date()' in the API request as an epoch timestamp in milliseconds, so that directions are returned based on date/time the user has selected and update each time this is changed. Obviously as default, without a date specified Google API returns directions for the current time.

**HTML for Date/Time Picker:**

```
<div id="timepicker">
<input id="datetimepicker" type="text" >
</div>
```

**Javascript for Date/Time Picker:**

```
jQuery('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
 format:'d.m.Y H:i',
 defaultTime:'15:00'
});
```

**Full script for my API request to toggle between travel modes and update map without letting the user specify an arrival time from the datetimepicker:**

```
<script> 
function initMap() {
var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;

var lattp = <?php echo json_encode($lattp);?>;
var lngtp = <?php echo json_encode($lngtp);?>;
var zoomtp = <?php echo json_encode($zoomtp);?>;
var tp = {lat: JSON.parse(lattp), lng: JSON.parse(lngtp)};

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  zoom: 14,
  center: tp
});
directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('right-panel'));

 if (navigator.geolocation) {
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
  var pos = {
    lat: position.coords.latitude,
    lng: position.coords.longitude
  };

  document.getElementsByName('radio').forEach(function(el){
    el.addEventListener('click', function() {
        calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay, pos);
    });

})

  calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay, pos);

}, function() {
  handleLocationError(true, markerme);
});
} else {
// Browser doesn't support Geolocation
window.alert('Geolocation is not supported');
} 
}

function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay, pos) {
//var selectedMode = document.getElementById('mode').value;
var selectedMode = "";
var radios = document.getElementsByName('radio')
radios.forEach(function(element) {
    if(element.checked){
        selectedMode = element.value;
    }
})

directionsService.route({
  origin: pos,  
  destination: {lat: *Value*,lng: *Value*},  
   travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode[selectedMode],
   transitOptions: {
   modes: ['RAIL'],
   arrivalTime: new Date(),
   routingPreference: 'FEWER_TRANSFERS'
},
    unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.IMPERIAL,
     provideRouteAlternatives: true
}, function(response, status) {

  if (status == 'OK') {
    directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
  } else {
    window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
  }
});
}
</script>
```

Thanks in advance for any help given - appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formatted input box is already one that a constructor to Date can parse.  Just pass in the value of your input box:

```
startDate = new Date(jquery('#datetimepicker').val());
```